# Connect Multiple Device using NsdManager

Tags: java, android

I have working on Android and I Need little bit Socket Programing in My Application.I want to Create my own Network Using NsdManager.I am Succefully Register my Service in network and Also Done Connection with Other Device.I have Successfully Transfer Data Between to Devices.

**Problem**

- Everthing is working Fine Also transfer message Between Two Devices but problem occur While I am Connect more than two Device.

**Requirement**

- I Want to Connect More Than Two Device and Share Data in All Connected Device.

**Brief Description of My Code**

Here I Have Two Class ChatConnection and NsdHalper.
ChatConnection is just for To Transfer Data between two Device and NsdHalper is provice Utility of NsdManger.

First I Register My Service in Network.

```
public void registerService(int port) {
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);
    serviceInfo.setServiceName(mServiceName);
    serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);
    
    mNsdManager.registerService(
            serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);
    
}
```

than Discover my Service

```
 public void discoverServices() {
    mNsdManager.discoverServices(
            SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
}
```

and I am Making One Custome Adapter For Listing All Available Device in my network.

```
  class DeviceListAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<NsdServiceInfo> {

    private List<NsdServiceInfo> items;
    private Context context;


    public DeviceListAdpater(Context context,
                             List<NsdServiceInfo> objects) {
        super(context, 0, 0, objects);
        this.context = context;
        items = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_device_list, parent, false);


        }
        NsdServiceInfo device = items.get(position);
        if (device != null) {
            TextView top = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_devicename);

            if (top != null) {
                top.setText(device.getServiceName());
            }

        }

        return v;

    }
}
```

and i have Also Done Following For To Connect Properly

```
public void initializeDiscoveryListener() {
    mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service);
            if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
            } else if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
            } else //if (service.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName))
            {
                getCallback().DeviceUpdate(service);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
            getCallback().ConnectionDone(service,false);
            if (mService == service) {
                mService = null;
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }
    };
}

public void initializeResolveListener() {
    mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
            getCallback().ConnectionDone(serviceInfo,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

            if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                return;
            }
            mService = serviceInfo;
            getCallback().ConnectionDone(serviceInfo,true);
        }
    };
}

public void initializeRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo NsdServiceInfo) {
            mServiceName = NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
            discoverServices();

        }
        
        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo arg0, int arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo arg0) {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
        }
        
    };
}
```

I hope you all are Clear with my Code.

and I Really need your help to Solve this problem.
Please Help if Anyone Connect Multiple Device Using NsdManager.

I have Making this application using [this](http://java.llp.dcc.ufmg.br:8080/apiminer/static/docs/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) Code Referance.

Thanks,

**Onik Answer.**

- Suppose I have 3 Device A1 A2 and A3.while all device successfull register in network and display Devices to Each other.While A1 is Request to Connect with A2 than A2 get pop up for Accept Connection or Decline If A2 Tapped on Connect than This Two Device Connect Successfull.Durinng This Session A3 is also want to Connect with A2 than A3 is Request to Connect With A2 than Again A2 get pop For Connection.
  Than **Problem Occurs**
  While A2 Tapped on Connect button than the Previous Connection Will be Losses.
  but my Requirement in to Previous Connection Still Remain while A3 connect with A2.

I hope Onik you Are Clear with my Problem.
and
In logCat nothing will be happen.while create new connection logcat will display same as while we connect at Previous connection.

Comment: Check Edit...I hope you are Clear with this.

Comment: Hi, did manage to solve this issue? I have a similar situation and i'd like some ideas on how to resolve this.